# DisjointSet in Inform 7

Tags: inform7

```
A DisjointSet is a kind of Object.
A DisjointSet is a part of every DisjointSet.
```

Trying to start a DisjointSet Object in Inform 7, but even though I know it could cause a infinite loop, I want to do it anyway for the obvious reason that it is part of the algorithm.

Here is the error

> You wrote 'A DisjointSet is a part of every DisjointSet' : but this
>   generalisation would be too dangerous, because it would lead to
>   infinite regress in the assembly process. Sometimes this happens if
>   you have set up matters with text like 'A container is in every
>   container.'.

I suppose it would be easier to do something like this in Inform 6, but I don't have any knowledge of it so I am trying to avoid it. But will accept help in Inform 6 too.

Edit following @jeroen-mostert advice:

Maybe I'm doing it wrong, but maybe some sample code might help.

```
A DisjointSet is a kind of Container.
A DisjointSet always contains a DisjointSet called the Parent.
The First Decl is a DisjointSet.
The Second Decl is a DisjointSet.
The Parent of the First Decl is the Second Decl. [This line doesn't work.]
```

> The sentence 'The Parent of the First Decl is the Second Decl'
>   appears to say two things are the same - I am reading 'Parent of the
>   First Decl' and 'Second Decl' as two different things, and therefore
>   it makes no sense to say that one is the other: it would be like
>   saying that 'St Peter is St Paul'. It would be all right if the second
>   thing were the name of a kind, perhaps with properties: for instance
>   'Pearly Gates is a lighted room' says that something called Pearly
>   Gates exists and that it is a 'room', which is a kind I know about,
>   combined with a property called 'lighted' which I also know about.

Comment: The error message provides a hint, I think -- Inform natively knows about containers, and that containers can't contain themselves (but could contain other containers). In fact, since an object can't be in two containers at once (except indirectly through nested containment) isn't it enough to simply *use* the Inform concept of a "container" as a disjoint set?

Comment: Maybe it helps if you tell us what algorithm you're trying to encode. The way I see it, this could take a while if you're trying to go piece by piece. Also, I have to ask what the point of your exercise is, since (as I hope is obvious) Inform, while being Turing complete, isn't exactly designed to handle this kind of reasoning about data structures.

Comment: It might be better to use relations rather than the object system.

Answer (score 1):

I'll give two answers. First, the question you asked:

## Linked lists in Inform 7

The problem is that **contains** and **is a part of** indicate physical concepts. When you use those words, Inform thinks you're talking about matter in the fictional universe, as if you said, "every bucket contains a bucket".

Instead, define your *own* property that has nothing to do with Inform's physical world model:

> Every DisjointSet **has** a DisjointSet called the Parent.

With this change, your code works.

Now on to the question you didn't ask:

## Relations in groups

If what you want is a bunch of sets of objects, where the sets are all disjoint, use an equivalence relation:

> **Friendship** relates people to each other in groups.

This defines a relation called "friendship" that divides all animals into disjoint sets, such that an animal is friends with the other animals in that set, and *not* friends with any other animal.

Then you must teach Inform a bit of vocabulary:

> The verb **to be friends with** means the friendship relation.

After that, the phrase "X is friends with Y" means that X and Y are in the same friendship set. You can say things like "Now the badger is friends with the giant squid" to update the sets.

See "Relations in groups" in the manual.